# Not Able to get entity data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am trying to edit an user entity.

When the password field is left blank, I want the password to remain the same in the database. But if the users enters a new password, I want it to update it.

I tried to get the password on the database in case the password field is left blank. But I get the following error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Nombre,Apellido,Password,RepeatPassword,IdRol,Email,Activo,ResetPassword,Username, Imagen, OldPassword")] Usuario usuario) {
    try {
        string OldPassword = db.Usuarios.Find(usuario.Id).Password;
        var password = "";
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario.Password) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario.RepeatPassword)) {

            password = OldPassword;

            if (ModelState.ContainsKey("Password")) ModelState["Password"].Errors.Clear();
            if (ModelState.ContainsKey("RepeatPassword")) ModelState["RepeatPassword"].Errors.Clear();
        } else {
            password = usuario.RepeatPassword;
            password = Encryption.EncryptPassword(password);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            usuario.Password = password;
            usuario.RepeatPassword = password;
            db.Entry(usuario).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            Sesion.Messages.Add(new UserMessage() {
                Type = MessageType.success, Message = "El Usuario se editó exitosamente"
            });
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.RolesList = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Id", "Nombre");
        return View(usuario);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.LogException(ex, ControllerContext);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update an existing element you should follow this pattern:

1) get the element from the repository using the Id

2) update the modified fields of the obtained element

3) save the element

This way entity framework does not try to create a new element with the same Id.

In your case you should replace

```
string OldPassword = db.Usuarios.Find(usuario.Id).Password;
...
```

with

```
var oldUser = db.Usuarios.Find(usuario.Id);
oldUser.Password = ...<new values>...
db.Entry(oldUser).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; //I thinks this is not required...
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thank you! works perfectly now!. Could you please explain why the ObjectStateManager would't save the original entity?

Comment: Asp.MVC has to create new instances of objects that are passed as parameters to actions. Then your original object is not Attached to Entity Framework context. An alternative solution (that i don't not recommended) would be to attach your object manually with db.Usuarios.Attach(usuario);

Comment: great! this is my first question in StackOverflow, I got the ritght answer in just a few minutes. :D thank you again, @DaniCE